# How does numpy's fromfile count argument work?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to read a binary file with numpy's fromfile function:

```
   f = open("01.wcf", 'r')
   wcf_header = np.fromfile(f, dtype=WC_IMAGE_DATA_HEADER_2, count=1)

   f.seek(5592)
   wcf = np.fromfile(f, dtype=WC_IMAGE_DATA, count=1)

   f.seek(6660)
   size = wcf['Width'] * wcf['Height']
   print size
   raw = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint16, count=size)
   print np.size(raw)
```

The first two calls work fine. I now know, that starting at 6660, there will be an image with size wcf['Width']*wcf['Height'] (in my case 512*512). So I pass this number, but the function only reads 283 values. Actually, it reads a maximum number of values of 283, i.e. for any value of count > 283 it only reads 283 values. For any value of count < 283 it reads the specified number of values.

When I pass count=-1 (i.e. read all values till the end of the file), it works, i.e. the file contains more values. However, as this binary-format allows for mulitple images, I need to specify the number of values I want to read.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try opening the file in binary mode: `f = open("01.wcf", 'rb')`

Comment: Thanks @Warren, now it works as expected!

Comment: Great.  I wasn't sure that was the cause of the problem, but since it is, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a binary file, so it should be opened in binary mode:

```
f = open("01.wcf", 'rb')
```